# How can I see approximate hours worked during the week with mercurial?

Tags: charts, mercurial, mercurial-extension

So I know about the [Mercurial activity extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ActivityExtension), however the data it seems to plot is number of commits. I don't think that is a good metric. If in an hour you make 20 commits or 1 commit, I don't think one can deduce much from that. I think it's far safer to say every time there is a commit we assume/input some previous time of work was done. 1-2 or maybe 5 hours (depending on the person). Then you plot that in a block style calendar widget (like github's contribution widget) either by week or by month...

Does anything like what I describe exist?

Comment: You want to get it for own Mercurial or just to see some concepts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'd like a solution to the problem posted,  to be used on any mercurial repository I wish.

Answer (score 0):

This has at the very least commit plotted by time of day:

https://bitbucket.org/fundacion_jala/stathg/wiki/Home

But it seems to be more of a point cloud rather than filling out blocks. This doesn't give one an idea as a percentage of the work week, how much has one worked. Not going to mark my answer as correct.